# Undefined references error

Tags: biblatex, citing, biber

I am working on a document and my citations have stoped working. It worked fine before but after a recent build citations stopped showing properly, with only IDs being displayed in the footnotes.

I usually work in atom with the latex plug in but for the sake of finding the problem I am running everything in the console. I tried to brake down everything into a more simple example but it is still not working.

Test.tex

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage[autocite=footnote]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{References.bib}

\begin{document}
Sample text I want to cite.\autocite[Vgl.][23]{Sandhaus2014}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

References.bib

```
@Book{Sandhaus2014,
author="Sandhaus, Gregor
and Berg, Bj{\"o}rn
and Knott, Philip",
Title="Hybride Softwareentwicklung: Das Beste aus klassischen und agilen Methoden in einem Modell vereint",
year="2014",
address="Berlin, Heidelberg",
Edition={7., aktualisierte Auflage}
}
```

I delete the auxiliary files and run in the console:

`pdflatex test -> biber test -> pdflatex test -> pdflatex test`

But I am constantly getting

*Citation "..." on page 1 undefined
There were undefined references*

errors.

test.log

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.21 (TeX Live 2020) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2021.1.19)  10 MAR 2021 15:38
entering extended mode
 restricted \write18 enabled.
 file:line:error style messages enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**test.tex
(./test.tex
LaTeX2e <2020-02-02> patch level 5
L3 programming layer <2020-03-06> (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/scrartcl.cls
Document Class: scrartcl 2020/01/24 v3.29 KOMA-Script document class (article)
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/scrkbase.sty
Package: scrkbase 2020/01/24 v3.29 KOMA-Script package (KOMA-Script-dependent basics and keyval usage)
 (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/scrbase.sty
Package: scrbase 2020/01/24 v3.29 KOMA-Script package (KOMA-Script-independent basics and keyval usage)
 (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty
Package: keyval 2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
\KV@toks@=\toks15
) (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/scrlfile.sty
Package: scrlfile 2020/01/24 v3.29 KOMA-Script package (loading files)
))) (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/tocbasic.sty
Package: tocbasic 2020/01/24 v3.29 KOMA-Script package (handling toc-files)
\scr@dte@tocline@numberwidth=\skip47
\scr@dte@tocline@numbox=\box45
)
Package tocbasic Info: omitting babel extension for `toc'
(tocbasic)             because of feature `nobabel' available
(tocbasic)             for `toc' on input line 137.
Package scrartcl Info: You've used standard option `12pt'.
(scrartcl)             This is correct!
(scrartcl)             Internally I'm using `fontsize=12pt'.
(scrartcl)             If you'd like to set the option with \KOMAoptions,
(scrartcl)             you'd have to use `fontsize=12pt' there
(scrartcl)             instead of `12pt', too.
Class scrartcl Info: File `scrsize12pt.clo' used to setup font sizes on input line 2212.
 (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/scrsize12pt.clo
File: scrsize12pt.clo 2020/01/24 v3.29 KOMA-Script font size class option (12pt)
) (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/typearea.sty
Package: typearea 2020/01/24 v3.29 KOMA-Script package (type area)
\ta@bcor=\skip48
\ta@div=\count167
Package typearea Info: You've used standard option `a4paper'.
(typearea)             This is correct!
(typearea)             Internally I'm using `paper=a4'.
(typearea)             If you'd like to set the option with \KOMAoptions,
(typearea)             you'd have to use `paper=a4' there
(typearea)             instead of `a4paper', too.
\ta@hblk=\skip49
\ta@vblk=\skip50
\ta@temp=\skip51
\footheight=\skip52
Package typearea Info: These are the values describing the layout:
(typearea)             DIV  = 12
(typearea)             BCOR = 0.0pt
(typearea)             \paperwidth      = 597.50793pt
(typearea)              \textwidth      = 448.13095pt
(typearea)              DIV departure   = -6%
(typearea)              \evensidemargin = 2.4185pt
(typearea)              \oddsidemargin  = 2.4185pt
(typearea)             \paperheight     = 845.04694pt
(typearea)              \textheight     = 635.5pt
(typearea)              \topmargin      = -41.72441pt
(typearea)              \headheight     = 18.125pt
(typearea)              \headsep        = 21.75pt
(typearea)              \topskip        = 12.0pt
(typearea)              \footskip       = 50.75pt
(typearea)              \baselineskip   = 14.5pt
(typearea)              on input line 1719.
)
\c@part=\count168
\c@section=\count169
\c@subsection=\count170
\c@subsubsection=\count171
\c@paragraph=\count172
\c@subparagraph=\count173
\scr@dte@section@maxnumwidth=\skip53
Class scrartcl Info: using compatibility default `runin=bysign'
(scrartcl)           for `\section on input line 4723.
Class scrartcl Info: using compatibility default `afterindent=bysign'
(scrartcl)           for `\section on input line 4723.
\scr@dte@part@maxnumwidth=\skip54
Class scrartcl Info: using compatibility default `afterindent=false'
(scrartcl)           for `\part on input line 4731.
\scr@dte@subsection@maxnumwidth=\skip55
Class scrartcl Info: using compatibility default `runin=bysign'
(scrartcl)           for `\subsection on input line 4741.
Class scrartcl Info: using compatibility default `afterindent=bysign'
(scrartcl)           for `\subsection on input line 4741.
\scr@dte@subsubsection@maxnumwidth=\skip56
Class scrartcl Info: using compatibility default `runin=bysign'
(scrartcl)           for `\subsubsection on input line 4751.
Class scrartcl Info: using compatibility default `afterindent=bysign'
(scrartcl)           for `\subsubsection on input line 4751.
\scr@dte@paragraph@maxnumwidth=\skip57
Class scrartcl Info: using compatibility default `runin=bysign'
(scrartcl)           for `\paragraph on input line 4761.
Class scrartcl Info: using compatibility default `afterindent=bysign'
(scrartcl)           for `\paragraph on input line 4761.
\scr@dte@subparagraph@maxnumwidth=\skip58
Class scrartcl Info: using compatibility default `runin=bysign'
(scrartcl)           for `\subparagraph on input line 4771.
Class scrartcl Info: using compatibility default `afterindent=bysign'
(scrartcl)           for `\subparagraph on input line 4771.
\abovecaptionskip=\skip59
\belowcaptionskip=\skip60
\c@pti@nb@sid@b@x=\box46
Package tocbasic Info: omitting babel extension for `lof'
(tocbasic)             because of feature `nobabel' available
(tocbasic)             for `lof' on input line 6002.
\scr@dte@figure@maxnumwidth=\skip61
\c@figure=\count174
Package tocbasic Info: omitting babel extension for `lot'
(tocbasic)             because of feature `nobabel' available
(tocbasic)             for `lot' on input line 6014.
\scr@dte@table@maxnumwidth=\skip62
\c@table=\count175
Class scrartcl Info: Redefining `\numberline' on input line 6178.
\bibindent=\dimen134
) (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/inputenc.sty
Package: inputenc 2018/08/11 v1.3c Input encoding file
\inpenc@prehook=\toks16
\inpenc@posthook=\toks17
) (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fontenc.sty
Package: fontenc 2020/02/11 v2.0o Standard LaTeX package
) (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/csquotes/csquotes.sty
Package: csquotes 2019-12-06 v5.2j context-sensitive quotations (JAW)
 (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/etoolbox/etoolbox.sty
Package: etoolbox 2019/09/21 v2.5h e-TeX tools for LaTeX (JAW)
\etb@tempcnta=\count176
)
\csq@reset=\count177
\csq@gtype=\count178
\csq@glevel=\count179
\csq@qlevel=\count180
\csq@maxlvl=\count181
\csq@tshold=\count182
\csq@ltx@everypar=\toks18
 (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/csquotes/csquotes.def
File: csquotes.def 2019-12-06 v5.2j csquotes generic definitions (JAW)
)
Package csquotes Info: Trying to load configuration file 'csquotes.cfg'...
Package csquotes Info: ... configuration file loaded successfully.
 (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/csquotes/csquotes.cfg
File: csquotes.cfg 
)) (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/babel.sty
Package: babel 2020/03/22 3.42 The Babel package

(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/switch.def
File: switch.def 2020/03/22 3.42 Babel switching mechanism
) (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel-german/ngerman.ldf
Language: ngerman 2018/12/08 v2.11 German support for babel (post-1996 orthography)
 (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel-german/ngermanb.ldf
Language: ngermanb 2018/12/08 v2.11 German support for babel (post-1996 orthography)
 (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/babel.def
File: babel.def 2020/03/22 3.42 Babel common definitions
\babel@savecnt=\count183
\U@D=\dimen135
 (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/txtbabel.def)
\bbl@readstream=\read2
\bbl@dirlevel=\count184
)
Package babel Info: Making " an active character on input line 121.
))) (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/biblatex.sty
Package: biblatex 2019/12/01 v3.14 programmable bibliographies (PK/MW)
 (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pdftexcmds/pdftexcmds.sty
Package: pdftexcmds 2019/11/24 v0.31 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO)
 (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/infwarerr/infwarerr.sty
Package: infwarerr 2019/12/03 v1.5 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
) (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/iftex.sty
Package: iftex 2020/03/06 v1.0d TeX engine tests
) (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ltxcmds/ltxcmds.sty
Package: ltxcmds 2019/12/15 v1.24 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
)
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdf@primitive is available.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdf@ifprimitive is available.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdfdraftmode found.
) (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/kvoptions/kvoptions.sty
Package: kvoptions 2019/11/29 v3.13 Key value format for package options (HO)
 (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/kvsetkeys/kvsetkeys.sty
Package: kvsetkeys 2019/12/15 v1.18 Key value parser (HO)
)) (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/logreq/logreq.sty
Package: logreq 2010/08/04 v1.0 xml request logger
\lrq@indent=\count185
 (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/logreq/logreq.def
File: logreq.def 2010/08/04 v1.0 logreq spec v1.0
))
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ifthen.sty
Package: ifthen 2014/09/29 v1.1c Standard LaTeX ifthen package (DPC)
) (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/url/url.sty
\Urlmuskip=\muskip16
Package: url 2013/09/16  ver 3.4  Verb mode for urls, etc.
)
\c@tabx@nest=\count186
\c@listtotal=\count187
\c@listcount=\count188
\c@liststart=\count189
\c@liststop=\count190
\c@citecount=\count191
\c@citetotal=\count192
\c@multicitecount=\count193
\c@multicitetotal=\count194
\c@instcount=\count195
\c@maxnames=\count196
\c@minnames=\count197
\c@maxitems=\count198
\c@minitems=\count199
\c@citecounter=\count266
\c@maxcitecounter=\count267
\c@savedcitecounter=\count268
\c@uniquelist=\count269
\c@uniquename=\count270
\c@refsection=\count271
\c@refsegment=\count272
\c@maxextratitle=\count273
\c@maxextratitleyear=\count274
\c@maxextraname=\count275
\c@maxextradate=\count276
\c@maxextraalpha=\count277
\c@abbrvpenalty=\count278
\c@highnamepenalty=\count279
\c@lownamepenalty=\count280
\c@maxparens=\count281
\c@parenlevel=\count282
\blx@tempcnta=\count283
\blx@tempcntb=\count284
\blx@tempcntc=\count285
\blx@maxsection=\count286
\blx@maxsegment@0=\count287
\blx@notetype=\count288
\blx@parenlevel@text=\count289
\blx@parenlevel@foot=\count290
\blx@sectionciteorder@0=\count291
\blx@entrysetcounter=\count292
\labelnumberwidth=\skip63
\labelalphawidth=\skip64
\biblabelsep=\skip65
\bibitemsep=\skip66
\bibnamesep=\skip67
\bibinitsep=\skip68
\bibparsep=\skip69
\bibhang=\skip70
\blx@bcfin=\read3
\blx@bcfout=\write3
\blx@langwohyphens=\language86
\c@mincomprange=\count293
\c@maxcomprange=\count294
\c@mincompwidth=\count295
Package biblatex Info: Trying to load biblatex default data model...
Package biblatex Info: ... file 'blx-dm.def' found.
 (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/blx-dm.def
File: blx-dm.def 2019/12/01 v3.14 biblatex localization (PK/MW)
)
Package biblatex Info: Trying to load biblatex custom data model...
Package biblatex Info: ... file 'biblatex-dm.cfg' not found.
\c@afterword=\count296
\c@savedafterword=\count297
\c@annotator=\count298
\c@savedannotator=\count299
\c@author=\count300
\c@savedauthor=\count301
\c@bookauthor=\count302
\c@savedbookauthor=\count303
\c@commentator=\count304
\c@savedcommentator=\count305
\c@editor=\count306
\c@savededitor=\count307
\c@editora=\count308
\c@savededitora=\count309
\c@editorb=\count310
\c@savededitorb=\count311
\c@editorc=\count312
\c@savededitorc=\count313
\c@foreword=\count314
\c@savedforeword=\count315
\c@holder=\count316
\c@savedholder=\count317
\c@introduction=\count318
\c@savedintroduction=\count319
\c@namea=\count320
\c@savednamea=\count321
\c@nameb=\count322
\c@savednameb=\count323
\c@namec=\count324
\c@savednamec=\count325
\c@translator=\count326
\c@savedtranslator=\count327
\c@shortauthor=\count328
\c@savedshortauthor=\count329
\c@shorteditor=\count330
\c@savedshorteditor=\count331
\c@labelname=\count332
\c@savedlabelname=\count333
\c@institution=\count334
\c@savedinstitution=\count335
\c@lista=\count336
\c@savedlista=\count337
\c@listb=\count338
\c@savedlistb=\count339
\c@listc=\count340
\c@savedlistc=\count341
\c@listd=\count342
\c@savedlistd=\count343
\c@liste=\count344
\c@savedliste=\count345
\c@listf=\count346
\c@savedlistf=\count347
\c@location=\count348
\c@savedlocation=\count349
\c@organization=\count350
\c@savedorganization=\count351
\c@origlocation=\count352
\c@savedoriglocation=\count353
\c@origpublisher=\count354
\c@savedorigpublisher=\count355
\c@publisher=\count356
\c@savedpublisher=\count357
\c@language=\count358
\c@savedlanguage=\count359
\c@origlanguage=\count360
\c@savedoriglanguage=\count361
\c@pageref=\count362
\c@savedpageref=\count363
\shorthandwidth=\skip71
\shortjournalwidth=\skip72
\shortserieswidth=\skip73
\shorttitlewidth=\skip74
\shortauthorwidth=\skip75
\shorteditorwidth=\skip76
\locallabelnumberwidth=\skip77
\locallabelalphawidth=\skip78
\localshorthandwidth=\skip79
\localshortjournalwidth=\skip80
\localshortserieswidth=\skip81
\localshorttitlewidth=\skip82
\localshortauthorwidth=\skip83
\localshorteditorwidth=\skip84
Package biblatex Info: Trying to load compatibility code...
Package biblatex Info: ... file 'blx-compat.def' found.
 (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/blx-compat.def
File: blx-compat.def 2019/12/01 v3.14 biblatex compatibility (PK/MW)
)
Package biblatex Info: Trying to load generic definitions...
Package biblatex Info: ... file 'biblatex.def' found.
 (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/biblatex.def
File: biblatex.def 2019/12/01 v3.14 biblatex compatibility (PK/MW)
\c@textcitecount=\count364
\c@textcitetotal=\count365
\c@textcitemaxnames=\count366
\c@biburlbigbreakpenalty=\count367
\c@biburlbreakpenalty=\count368
\c@biburlnumpenalty=\count369
\c@biburlucpenalty=\count370
\c@biburllcpenalty=\count371
\biburlbigskip=\muskip17
\biburlnumskip=\muskip18
\biburlucskip=\muskip19
\biburllcskip=\muskip20
\c@smartand=\count372
)
Package biblatex Info: Trying to load bibliography style 'numeric'...
Package biblatex Info: ... file 'numeric.bbx' found.
 (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/bbx/numeric.bbx
File: numeric.bbx 2019/12/01 v3.14 biblatex bibliography style (PK/MW)
Package biblatex Info: Trying to load bibliography style 'standard'...
Package biblatex Info: ... file 'standard.bbx' found.
 (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/bbx/standard.bbx
File: standard.bbx 2019/12/01 v3.14 biblatex bibliography style (PK/MW)
\c@bbx:relatedcount=\count373
\c@bbx:relatedtotal=\count374
))
Package biblatex Info: Trying to load citation style 'numeric'...
Package biblatex Info: ... file 'numeric.cbx' found.
 (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/cbx/numeric.cbx
File: numeric.cbx 2019/12/01 v3.14 biblatex citation style (PK/MW)
Package biblatex Info: Redefining '\cite'.
Package biblatex Info: Redefining '\parencite'.
Package biblatex Info: Redefining '\footcite'.
Package biblatex Info: Redefining '\footcitetext'.
Package biblatex Info: Redefining '\smartcite'.
Package biblatex Info: Redefining '\supercite'.
Package biblatex Info: Redefining '\textcite'.
Package biblatex Info: Redefining '\textcites'.
Package biblatex Info: Redefining '\cites'.
Package biblatex Info: Redefining '\parencites'.
Package biblatex Info: Redefining '\smartcites'.
)
Package biblatex Info: Trying to load configuration file...
Package biblatex Info: ... file 'biblatex.cfg' found.
 (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/biblatex.cfg
File: biblatex.cfg 
))
Package csquotes Info: Checking for multilingual support...
Package csquotes Info: ... found 'babel' package.
Package csquotes Info: Adjusting default style.
Package csquotes Info: Redefining alias 'default' -> 'ngerman'.
 (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-pdfmode.def
File: l3backend-pdfmode.def 2020-03-12 L3 backend support: PDF mode
\l__kernel_color_stack_int=\count375
\l__pdf_internal_box=\box47
) (./test.aux)
\openout1 = `test.aux'.

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 12.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 12.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 12.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 12.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 12.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 12.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 12.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 12.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for TS1/cmr/m/n on input line 12.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 12.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 12.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 12.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 12.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 12.
Package biblatex Info: Trying to load language 'ngerman'...
Package biblatex Info: ... file 'ngerman.lbx' found.
 (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/lbx/ngerman.lbx
File: ngerman.lbx 2019/12/01 v3.14 biblatex localization (PK/MW)
Package biblatex Info: Trying to load language 'german'...
Package biblatex Info: ... file 'german.lbx' found.
 (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/lbx/german.lbx
File: german.lbx 2019/12/01 v3.14 biblatex localization (PK/MW)
)
Package biblatex Info: Trying to load language 'german'...
Package biblatex Info: ... file 'german.lbx' found.
 (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/lbx/german.lbx
File: german.lbx 2019/12/01 v3.14 biblatex localization (PK/MW)
))
Package biblatex Info: Input encoding 'utf8' detected.
Package biblatex Info: Automatic encoding selection.
(biblatex)             Assuming data encoding 'utf8'.
\openout3 = `test.bcf'.

Package biblatex Info: Trying to load bibliographic data...
Package biblatex Info: ... file 'test.bbl' found.
 (./test.bbl)
Package biblatex Info: Reference section=0 on input line 12.
Package biblatex Info: Reference segment=0 on input line 12.
LaTeX Font Info:    External font `cmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <12> on input line 13.
LaTeX Font Info:    External font `cmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <8> on input line 13.
LaTeX Font Info:    External font `cmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <6> on input line 13.
LaTeX Font Info:    External font `cmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <7> on input line 13.
LaTeX Font Info:    External font `cmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <5> on input line 13.


LaTeX Warning: Citation 'Sandhaus2014' on page 1 undefined on input line 13.


LaTeX Warning: Empty bibliography on input line 16.

[1

{/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}] (./test.aux)

LaTeX Warning: There were undefined references.


Package biblatex Warning: Please (re)run Biber on the file:
(biblatex)                test
(biblatex)                and rerun LaTeX afterwards.

Package logreq Info: Writing requests to 'test.run.xml'.
\openout1 = `test.run.xml'.

 ) 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 11751 strings out of 480608
 225802 string characters out of 5903630
 993062 words of memory out of 5000000
 27572 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
 538909 words of font info for 38 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
 1143 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 45i,8n,56p,10099b,2193s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,80000s
{/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/enc/dvips/cm-super/cm-super-t1.enc}</usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/cm-super/sfbx1000.pfb></usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/cm-super/sfrm0700.pfb></usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/cm-super/sfrm0800.pfb></usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/cm-super/sfrm1000.pfb></usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/cm-super/sfrm1200.pfb>
Output written on test.pdf (1 page, 41345 bytes).
PDF statistics:
 29 PDF objects out of 1000 (max. 8388607)
 20 compressed objects within 1 object stream
 0 named destinations out of 1000 (max. 500000)
 1 words of extra memory for PDF output out of 10000 (max. 10000000)
```

I am confused since everything was working as expected. The problem first occurred after adding a addition reference and rebuilding the file. Even after removing the added reference I did not work as before. I am looking for advice on how to solve this issue.

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.  When you are processing from the command line, the bibliography must be processed separately.  (When using a front end or editor, this is often done automatically.)  This question explains the process: [biblatex in a nutshell](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/13509)

Comment: Your MWE works for me with pdflatex->bibtex->pdflatex->pdflatex

Comment: Running pdflatex->bibtex->pdflatex->pdflatex gives me the following error: I found no \citation commands---while reading file test.aux
I found no \bibdata command---while reading file test.aux
I found no \bibstyle command---while reading file test.aux

Upon researching that one I found lots of answers instructing to use Biber instead of bibtex so now I am confused.

Comment: My bad, my IDE used biber automatically. so it was pdflatex->biber->pdflatex->pdflatex. On the first pdflatex you get a warning of undefined reference (and on the second). On the last pdflatex all warnings disappear and you get a pdf with the reference...

Comment: That is the behaviour I was expecting but I still get the same error after the last run. The log file I added is taken after the last run of pdflatex. If it is indeed working for you but not for me on the same files what could I do to further diagnose the problem on my end?

Comment: The example works fine for me. If you did indeed run Biber, you should find its log file (the`.blg` file) in the same folder as your main `.tex` file and its `.log` file. Open it and paste it here.

Comment: Interesting. I seem to have resolved the problem and I think biber was to blame. I cleared the biber cache. I did not work the first time but after clearing it again it was back to working for me as well. The problem reappeared though and I had to clear the cache again to resolve it.